# Detecting anomalies among several thousand users

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, time-series, outliers, anomaly-detection

I have this issue where I record a daily entry for all users in my system (several thousands, even 100.000+). These entries have 3 main features, "date", "file_count", "user_id".

| date | file_count | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-09-28 | 200 | 5 |
| 2021-09-28 | 10 | 7 |
| 2021-09-29 | 210 | 5 |
| 2021-09-29 | 50 | 7 |

Where I am in doubt is how to run an anomaly detection algorithm efficiently on all these users.
My goal is to be able to report whether a user has some abnormal behavior each day.

In this example, user 7 should be flagged as an anomaly because the file_count suddenly is x5 higher than "normal".

My idea was firstly to create a model for each user but since there are so many users this might not be feasible.

Could you help explain me how to do this in an efficient manner if you know an algorithm that could solve this problem?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Article for anomaly detection in audit data can be found many on the Internet.
One simple article with many of examples/approaches can be found in original (Czech) language here: https://blog.root.cz/trpaslikuv-blog/detekce-anomalii-v-auditnich-zaznamech-casove-rady/ or translated using google technology: https://blog-root-cz.translate.goog/trpaslikuv-blog/detekce-anomalii-v-auditnich-zaznamech-casove-rady/?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=sk&_x_tr_pto=wapp

PS: Clustering (Clustering Based Unsupervised Approach) can be way to go, when searching for simple algorithm.

Comment: In regards to clustering, how would you structure the data? 
Would you have X features, one for each user (X users), at each date? 
This is at least the idea that I had, but I fear that the curse of dimensionality might ruin this.

Comment: I have no own knowledge, but I would try to have a look at some easy to use sw to make more than one approach to problem. I would try to use weka https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/ for example. I think you can buy working solution, or you need to do "research" on your own data to gain something working.